# How can I access values in a nested mongodb object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object

I have a Company mongodb structure like this:

```
{ "companyName" : "SomeCompany",


"Products" : [
        {
            "productId" : "e3rQACssGkfp9zsue",
            "productCode" : "271102502",
            "memberPrice" : "200",
        },
        {
            "productId" : "e3rQACssGkfp9zsue",
            "productCode" : "271102502",
            "memberPrice" : "500",
        },
    ]
}
```

Each Company has a nested object called Products, which has its own attributes. How can I loop through the object to print out just the memberPrice from Products? I am trying to do something like:

```
console.log(Company.Products.memberPrice)
```

which returns undefined...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the array's [**`forEach()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to iterate over the element's property:

```
var obj = { 
    "companyName" : "SomeCompany",
    "Products" : [
        {
            "productId" : "e3rQACssGkfp9zsue",
            "productCode" : "271102502",
            "memberPrice" : "200",
        },
        {
            "productId" : "e3rQACssGkfp9zsue",
            "productCode" : "271102502",
            "memberPrice" : "500",
        },
    ]
};

obj.Products.forEach(function(product){
    console.log(product.memberPrice); // 200, 500
})
```

---

-- **UPDATE** --

You could consider the following (thanks to @Michael) if you want to iterate the object in mongo shell, using the [**`find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find) cursor's [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach) method:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){
    doc.Products.forEach(function(p){ 
        print(p.memberPrice);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Michael [**Fastest gun in the west**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) :P

Comment: One more thing since OP tags question `mongodb`. why not something like db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){doc.Products.forEach(function(p){ print(p.memberPrice)})})

Comment: @Michael That's another possible solution as well, kudos for mentioning!